# What is the difference between DC base current and signal current in CE transistor amplifier?

Tags: bjt, small-signal

I came across a sentence that " if the DC base current has to be 10 times the signal current....".I could not understand, what is DC base current as I have just read about Input current and Output current? And also what quantity (like current gain{beta}, ratio of current through collector and current through emitter, etc.) is the mentioned statement asking for?

Comment: The sentence is relevant if you're amplifying AC, not DC. It keeps the AC analysis simple because the signal has very little effect on the (DC) bias conditions.

Answer (score 2):

**Two alternatives:**

1.) The "DC base current" is the DC current through the voltage divider that provides the necessary base voltage.

Background: Normally, we require that this current should be much larger than the DC current into the base node (as a "rule of thumb": Factor 10 at least).

This is because the produced base voltage Vb should be "stiff" enough and less sensitive to the large tolerances/uncertainties of the DC base current Ib.

2.) The signal current into the base ib (caused by the applied signal voltage) should be much smaller (rule of thumb: Factor 10) than the DC bias current Ib into the base.

This condition (ib<<Ib) will ensure a sufficiently good linearity between signal input current ib and signal output current ic - and, hence, a good linearity between input and output (amplified) voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If the *total* base current is denoted with \$i_B(t)\$, and if the *time average value* (DC value) of \$i_B(t)\$ is denoted with \$I_B\$, then denote the AC (signal) base current as

$$i_b(t) = i_B(t) - I_B$$

and the sentence you came across can be written as "if \$I_B\$ has to be about \$10\cdot i_b(t)\$..."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ore9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Input is a 100mV (peak) sinusoid, which gets couple to the base via C1. Base current \$I_B\$, resulting from the ±0.1V fluctuations in base potential, looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the average DC value of \$I_B\$ (the lower green marker) is a little over 4μA. That's what we call the "DC component" of the signal current. The "AC component" is the amplitude of those oscillations, which is only 700nA or so.

In this example, the DC component of the signal is clearly *less than* 10 times the AC component, which isn't ideal. One reason why we want a big difference (a factor of ten) is that we never want the signal to ever get anywhere near zero, which would cause severe distortion, such as clipping.

The bigger reason, though, has to do with linearity. Unfortunately, the graph of \$I_C\$ vs. \$I_B\$ is not a straight line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzTLhT.png)</sup>

Here's \$I_C\$ (orange) as I sweep \$I_B\$. Blue is a straight line for comparison:

[image]

The gradient of the line is the current gain, \$\beta = \frac{\Delta I_C}{\Delta I_B}\$, but it's not constant. Here's it's about 150, but to the left of centre it's more, to the right it's less. That means that depending on the DC operating point, the place on that curve about which your signal currents are fluctuating, you'll find slightly different gains.

<sub>Note: You may notice that in my first circuit above, I carefully chose R3 and R4 to produce a DC operating point of \$I_B=4\mu A\$, smack in the middle of the curve, half way between cut-off and saturation (where the orange plot flattens).</sub>

This curved graph means that you cannot say that changes in \$I_B\$ result in perfectly proportional changes in \$I_C\$. This slightly non-linear relationship will introduce signal distortion.

However, if you constrain the region of that graph through which \$I_B\$ sweeps, the straighter the corresponding section of orange line \$I_C\$ is. Think of "zooming in" on a very small region of the orange curve, corresponding to the AC component's amplitude; the section of line appears straighter and straighter, the more you zoom in. In other words, by constraining the amplitude of changes in \$I_B\$, the more linear the response of \$I_C\$.

That gives us the rule of thumb that, for best linearity, you aim to keep the DC component of \$I_B\$ somewhere near the middle of that graph (at least, far from either extreme of cut-off or saturation), and have fluctuations (AC component) not more than ±10% of that DC value.

Perhaps a better rule of thumb would be to ensure that the AC component never gets more than *10% of the way* to either extreme of cut-off or saturation, depending on which is closer.

Of course, your own application may not require good linearity, in which case you can disregard this "DC is ten times AC" guideline. For example, the transistor circuitry inside an op-amp can be highly non-linear, but it doesn't matter because negative feedback outside the op-amp linearises everything.